# How to make Sticky Sidebar like Facebook in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, next.js, sidebar, sticky

I'm trying to make a sticky sidebar in NestJS like Facebook has, but when I scroll the content of the page, the sidebar in it also scrolls and it shouldn't. It should work independently and only scroll when it is scrolled even though it is in the parent element that is scrolling. Does anyone know what it should look like correctly?

**Home Page Code:**

```
import Header from "../components/Header";
import NavBar from "../components/NavBar";
import SideBar from "../components/home/SideBar";
import CreatePost from "../components/CreatePost";
import Posts from "../components/Posts";

import Announcements from "../components/Announcements";

import "../components/home/Home.css";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const HomePage = () => {

  const pageContentRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const sidebarRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  return (
    <div className="theme-dark">
      <Header />
      <div className="main-content" id="main-content">
        <NavBar />
        <main className="page-content" id="page-content" ref={pageContentRef}>
          <div className="page-wrapper">
            <div className="page-subcontent" id="home-page">
              <div className="container">
                <div className="page-inner">
                  <div className="page-outer">
                    <CreatePost />
                    <Posts />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <SideBar pageContentRef={pageContentRef} sidebarRef={sidebarRef} />
          </div>
        </main>
        <Announcements />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
  
export default HomePage;
```

**Sidebar Code:**

```
import "./SideBar.css"
import { useEffect } from "react";

const SideBar = ({ pageContentRef, sidebarRef })  => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const sidebar = sidebarRef.current;

    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (sidebar) {
        sidebar.style.transform = `translateY(${pageContentRef.current.scrollTop}px)`;
      }
    };

    sidebar.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => {
      sidebar.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, [sidebarRef]);

  return (
    <div className="page-sidebar" id="sidebar" ref={sidebarRef}>
      <div className="sidebar-inner">
        <div className="sidebar-header">
            <h3 className="sidebar-headding">Section #1</h3>
            <h3 className="sidebar-headding">Section #2</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar-list" id="online-friends">
            <h3 className="sidebar-headding"><i className="fas fa-user-friends"></i> Dostępni Znajomi</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SideBar;
```

**CSS Styles:**

```
#page-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 56px;
    left: 61px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: calc(100% - 61px);
    min-height: calc(100vh - 56px);
}

.page-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#sidebar {
    position: sticky;
    top: 56px;
    bottom: 0;
    flex-basis: 360px;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 360px;
    min-height: inherit;
    height: calc(100vh - 56px);
    background-color: #252525;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar > .sidebar-inner {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 0 16px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```